# Retrieving a file and writing to a temp file from S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, sftp

I need to be able to store a file, then access it for a celery task. Is there a way, when I return a s3_file_path I can download and store the file in the temporary file location? I saw the key.get_contents_to_filename('some_name') but that doesn't really serve my purpose. I would return the s3_file_path and then perform my actions commented in the celery task pseudo code, in another function. I am currently doing a hacky version of this by making an expired url using the generate_url(), but it's not really what I want to do.

```
conn = boto.connect_s3()

# TODO: add test to check for validate=False
bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.S3_BACKUP_BUCKET, validate=False)
key = Key(bucket)

s3_file_path = os.path.join(
    settings.ENVIRONMENT, location, destination_filename)
key.key = s3_file_path
key.set_contents_from_filename(source_filename)

# celery task code
# bucket.download(s3_file_path, tempfile_name)
# file_obj = open(tempfile_name, 'r')
# import_file(file_obj)
```